# Excel VBA Email notification when fail/sucess to Unlock sheet/workbook with Username

Tags: excel, vba, email, notifications

I've got a workbook that I share with a lot of people, and some parts are protected, as I don't want them to see hidden sheets, rows and columns.

Is there a possibility to have a VBA code that will send a email notification to creator of the workbook if a user tries to unlock the sheet / workbook, both fails and successes, with the users Username in windows and/or in Excel, without the user knowing it (Sees it)?

And the same if the user tries to look at the VBA codes or try to unhide hidden sheets, rows and/or columns?

I thank you all in advance, and if I'm vague somewhere, or if you have any questions, please let me know.

Best Regards,

Comment: The unlocking of a workbook and whether this is a failed or successful attempt isn't a part of Excel's Worksheet Events so it would be difficult to initiate directly from this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet_events.aspx). Your best bet would be to write your own password prompt with successful/failed attempt handling

Comment: Side Note: Be aware that sending personal user data/information like username (which can be the real name) without letting the user know can be against laws or employee rights. This might depend on your country or the country these files are going to be used in.

Comment: Jordan - That sounds like a good option, thanks for that! :)
Peh - Your're right, didnt think about it, thanks for the heads up :)